# SQL query to match table with multiple rows from another

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for the poorly worded question.

I have two tables, called **conversations** and **conversation_users**. Each conversation can have multiple users attached to it. The fields are as follows:

**conversations**

- conv_id
- conv_author_id
- conv_date

**conversation_users**

- cu_id
- cu_conv_id
- cu_user_id

Now, to avoid duplication of conversations with the same users. I want to check whether a conversation already exists with users with ID, say 12 and 25. If one exists, I wish to obtain the ID of that conversation.

How do I go about structuring a query to do this?

Comment: MySQL, Unless you  meant something else? :p

Comment: How are the multiple users stored on the conversations table? Are there multiple rows with the same conv_id and different conv_author_id values?

Comment: All users participating in a conversation are stored in conversation_users. The author_id is just to track who started the conversation.

Comment: @emkay just saw that you added the tag before answering my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check whether a conversation already **exists** with users with
>   ID, say 12 and 25.

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM conversation_users cu
    WHERE cu.cu_conv_id = c.conv_id
    AND   cu.cu_user_id IN (12, 25)
) THEN 'Yes, these users are in this conversation' 
  ELSE 'This conversation is between different users' END AS Result
FROM conversations c
```